# How to watch events on App Engine Datastore using Java?

Tags: java, database, google-app-engine

I would like to know if is there someone that have done something similar or know if Google App Engines suports to listen events to the datastore.

Example: Let's say I need to be able to know if a specific product hasn't sell much as I was expecting and set somewhere to run an event when the quantity of the product gets less than x quantity per month.

Can we set a event listener on the datastore or the only way to accomplish is to set a task to run from time to time to check this out ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

check out [cloud 2 device messaging ]: http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/
it's pretty tightly integrated with GAE if you're using that already.

unfortunately i can't help you much with setting it up since I'm still working on that myself..

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is a better way to do this now using the Datastore Callbacks.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/callbacks

Answer (score 0):

yeah,of course,you can set a Log4j to log the operations.If you want to set a trigger on somewhere,you can use Cron or Spring quartz,that will solve your problem.You can use Cron to set a time,and Spring quartz to set a event.
you can find cron here,https://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron.html
quartz here,http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Comment: Hi Pigletfly, I'll have a look on the links you sent and get back with my findings. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this using the [Prospective Search API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/prospectivesearch/). Every time an event occurs that you might want to listen on, send a document to the API, which will call any hooked events.

The example you describe, though, doesn't fit because it's more of a non-event - something that failed to happen. For something like that, you'd need to run a regular task using cron or the task queue, and check if the condition was satisfied in that time interval.